# How can I have white urls in all the selected li-s?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-lists

I made a jQuery vertical drop down menu and I want to have white urls in all li-s hovered, not just the last one.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left_menu">


    <ul class="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu_categories">Categories</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu_categories_add">Add category</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu_categories">Manage categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>



        <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu_pages">Galleries</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu_pages_add">Add gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu_pages">Manage galleries</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>



        <li>
            <a href="#" class="menu_pages">Pages</a>

            <ul>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="menu_pages_add">Add page</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" class="menu_pages_add">Add page</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="menu_pages">Manage pages</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>


                <li><a href="#" class="menu_pages">Manage pages</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>



        <li><a href="#" class="menu_settings">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>


</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.left_menu {
    width: 219px;
}

.menu li {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
    border-right: 1px solid #222222;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

.menu li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}

.menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -34px 0 0 219px;
    width: 219px;
}

.menu li ul li {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

.menu li ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('.menu li').hover(function(){
     $(this).children('ul').show();
}, function(){
     $(this).children('ul').hide();
});
```

Please take a look here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xg6jR/)

Also if you think you can improve my CSS and jQuery you are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean you want parent li's to have a hover state when child elements are hovered?

Comment: Yes, I don't think I understand what you want. As written, it sounds like you want text to turn white when hovered over but...stay white when the mouse leaves? (In which case you can just use the mouseEnter event instead of hover)

Comment: It's also worth noting that you dont actually need jQuery to do this, you can make multilevel menus with just css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/Xg6jR/3/

What I did was change the hover from on the a tag to the li tag which, and modified the path to be immediate to the a:

```
.menu li:hover > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I also added the below line and remove the jQuery all together to make the menu show without javascript.

```
 .menu li:hover > ul {
      display: block;   
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the CSS to this:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.left_menu {
    width: 219px;
}

.menu li {
    font-weight: 300;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 12px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
    border-right: 1px solid #222222;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

.menu li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}

.menu li:hover > a {
    color: #fff;
}

.menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #666666;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.menu li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    margin: -34px 0 0 219px;
    width: 219px;
}

.menu li ul li {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
}

.menu li ul li:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your CSS:

```
.menu > li:hover > a, .menu > li > ul li:hover a {color: white}
```